# Does openGL supprots multiple geometry shaders in series?

Tags: glsl, geometry-shader

I wish to pipe 2 geometry shaders. The first one takes one point and releases multiple points. The second one takes one of those points and releases a rectangle to fragment shader.

Geometry shader 1:

```
layout (points) in;
layout (points, max_vertices = 16) out;

in GEO1 {
    uint name_tile_atlas;
    uint name_tile_map;
    uint subtiles;
} geo1[];

out GEO2 {
    vec2 pos_ones_atlas;
    vec2 pos_ones_target;
} geo2;

void main {...}
```

Geometry shader 2:

```
layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

in GEO2 {
    vec2 pos_ones_atlas;
    vec2 pos_ones_target;
} geo2[];

out vec2 frag_uv;

void main {...}
```

I naively attached those geometry shaders to one program, and they goes to a single geometry stage which can only have one main function. Is there anyway to pipe these shaders? 
I can merge them by moving code in shader2 into a forloop, but I don't want to loop 16 times for parallelizable logic, and it's getting worse when piping arbitrary number geometry shaders...

Comment: No. There can be only one geometry shader stage, and the geometry shader can generate only one type of primitives.

Comment: Each shader stage in the OpenGL pipeline (vertex, geometry, fragment, etc.) has a single entry point, and you cannot have multiple main functions within a single stage. To improve performance when processing a larger number of inputs, you can utilize instanced rendering. This allows you to issue a single draw call with multiple instances, and each instance can have different input data. In your case, you could set up a single geometry shader that processes multiple instances, each with its own input data. See the for loops in shader programs at https://ogldev.org/www/tutorial33/tutorial33.html